# Importação do Electron no Node retorna "undefined"

Tags: node.js, electron

Estou querendo utilizar o Electron com Node, porém ao importar esse framework seguindo o passo a passo do [tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app#desenvolvimento-electron-em-um-nutshell) do site, ele retorna sempre `undefined`.

```
// Abaixo tanto o "app" quanto o "BrowserWindow" são undefined.
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
```

Eu realizei a instalação do Electron utilizando o comando `npm install electron`. Testei importar tudo para saber o que retornava e o que eu recebi foi o caminho absoluto para um executável chamado `electron.exe`.

```
// Retorna o seguinte path: "C:\\...\\MyFolder\\node_modules\\electron\\dist\\electron.exe"
const electron = require("electron");
```

O que eu estou fazendo de errado? Não houve nenhum erro durante a instalação do framework.

Comment: Você está executando o código via terminal (fora da IDE)? https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8200#issuecomment-266923546

Comment: Estou executando o código via terminal. No primeiro exemplo eu executei através do `node main.js` e na segunda vez executei através do modo interativo do Node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instale o Electron GLOBALMENTE assim:

```
npm install electron -g
```

Depois acesse a sua pasta e execute o seu comando:

```
cd pasta/projeto
electron .
```

A sua pasta deve conter os arquivos como:

```
seu-app/
├── package.json
├── main.js
└── index.html
```

Comment: Instalei globalmente o electron e quando tentei executar, ele estava dando uma mensagem de erro dizendo que não conseguia encontrar o módulo. Aí eu vi a árvore que você colocou na resposta e percebi que eu não tinha o arquivo `package.json`. Então tive que criar com o `npm init`. Depois disso funcionou.

Comment: Mas por que é preciso instalar o electron globalmente ? O que isso muda ? E por que eu preciso ter o arquivo `package.json` para executar o electron ?

Comment: Pra criar localmente você teria que editar no package.json e adicionar o comando apontando para ele, fora que tem que instalar com o parametro `--save-dev` e você deve ter esquecido .... fora que não existir o package.json já é problema o suficiente, porque significa que NÃO TINHA NADA instalado.